# C# Build event failed

Tags: c#, nhibernate, visual-studio-2012, build

I am trying to setup NHibernate for the first time. following the tutorial at: [Your first Nhibernate application](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx)

I am told to add the following post build  event:

```
copy $(ProjectDir)..\..\SharedLibs\sqlce*.dll $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)
```

However when i build the application i get the following error:

```
Error   1   The command "copy c:\users\marc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FirstSolution\FirstSolution.Tests\..\..\SharedLibs\sqlce*.dll c:\users\marc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FirstSolution\FirstSolution.Tests\bin\Debug\" exited with code 1.   FirstSolution.Tests
```

I am fairly new to C# and visual studio in general can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the spaces in your path are causing this problem. Replacing your post-build event command with this one that surrounds the paths with double quotes:

`copy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\SharedLibs\sqlce*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"`

should do the trick for you. Another, not so practical, option is to remove the spaces from all referenced folders' names.